# creating a sentence if the minimum score is below its column average

Tags: r

This is what I have:

```
canada <- c(90, 50, 90)
korea <- c(60, 30, 90)
iran <- c(40, 20, 40)
fruit <- rbind(canada, korea, iran)
colnames(fruit) <- c("apple", "banana", "orange")

price <- function(val){
  val <- tolower(val) # assuming all row names are in lower case
  myrow <- fruit[val,]
  nation <- tools::toTitleCase(val)

  name.max <- names(myrow)[which.max(c(myrow))]
  name.min <- names(myrow)[which.min(c(myrow))]
  score.max <- c(myrow)[which.max(c(myrow))]
  score.min <- c(myrow)[which.min(c(myrow))]

  range <- c(paste0(nation, " has cheap fruit, ", score.min, " cents for one ", name.min, "."))
  cat(range)
}

> price("iran")
Iran has cheap fruit, 20 cents for banana.
```

The script uses *which.min* to provide which cell of the selected row has the lowest score.

Canada's cheapest fruit is banana with the price of 50 cents, but it is still above average. I want the computer to print only if the price of the banana is above average, producing a sentence like this:

```
> price("canada")
Canada's cheapest fruit is banana, but it is still more expensive than the average.
```

I can always manually type in the column average and use operation signs, but I was hoping if there would be a function I can incorporate into what  I currently have.

Comment: So what is the case? You type country, the output you get is the cheapest fruit and price.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to read my question. The cheapest fruit is the banana, but the price is still above average. I want the computer to print only if the price of the banana is above average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
canada <- c(90, 50, 90)
korea <- c(60, 30, 90)
iran <- c(40, 20, 40)
fruit <- rbind(canada, korea, iran)
colnames(fruit) <- c("apple", "banana", "orange")

price <- function(val){
  val <- tolower(val) # assuming all row names are in lower case
  myrow <- fruit[val,]
  nation <- tools::toTitleCase(val)

  name.min <- names(myrow)[which.min(c(myrow))]
  score.min <- c(myrow)[which.min(c(myrow))]

  if (score.min < mean(fruit[, name.min])) {
    cat(paste0(nation, "'s cheapest fruit is ", name.min, 
               ", and it is cheaper than the average."))
  } else {
    cat(paste0(nation, "'s cheapest fruit is ", name.min, 
               ", but it is still more expensive than the average."))
  }
}
```

> ```
> > price("iran")
> Iran's cheapest fruit is banana, and it is cheaper than the average.
> > price("canada")
> Canada's cheapest fruit is banana, but it is still more expensive than the average.
> ```

Comment: This will do! One quick question. In score.min < mean(fruit[, name.min], why did you use name.min to grab the column means rather than using the score.min ?

Comment: Because the actual score would need to be compared to all scores in each column and may have multiple matches. For example, what column should be chosen if the `score.min` is 90?

Comment: I would have to think it through. My brain is still trying to digest all this right now. But, thank you so much. This answer will help us with making this world a safer place to live; I'm not using it for fruit prices :)